# Common platform for submitting reccomendations for grad school

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I get requested  by 5 to 6 students every year to give a reccomendation for admission to  graduate school. I find that the typical student applies to 6 to 8 universities.

Most of the schools send a link for me to submit the reccomendations at and all  have a relatively similar set of questions for recommenders. It takes a lot of time to upload all these reccomendations with duplication of effort.

I was wondering if there are already any apps or websites that streamline this process by automating the sharing of reccomendation information.

For context this is an engineering program.